# javascript: need press button twice for onclick to trigger

Tags: javascript, php, html

In advance, I apologize to the programmers of our world if my code is ugly and is not in the correct mold. I'm doing this, because where I work nobody else knows programming. :)

I created a page to download some certificates. After the user authenticates, he is redirected to the certificate download page. Until this moment, when the user authenticates, the certificate will be automatically generated, but I would like to put a button for the user to click if they really wanted to generate the certificates.

At first it looks like this:

```
<div class="form">
        <p><strong><span>Usuário: <?= $_SESSION['user'] ?></span></strong></p>
        <form action="protected.php" id="my_form" method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="gen_cert" value="Gerar certificados" onclick="switcher('gen_cert');this.disabled=true;" />
        </form>
        <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['gen_cert'])) { ?>
                        <?php require("cert_generate.php"); ?>
                        <div id="gen_cert" style="display:none">
                        <p><a href="download.php?fid=<?= $_SESSION['user'].".p12" ?>" class="button" >Download do certificado pessoal</a></p>
                        <p><a href="download.php?fid=ca.crt" class="button" >Download da CA</a></p>
                        </div>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Yes, I have html tags inside php. At first it was the only way that I came up with the `"cert_generate.php" check by "if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"` and `isset($_POST['gen_cert']))"`.

***UPDATED***

**SCRIPT**

```
   function switcher() {
        var x = document.getElementById("generator");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
        }
}
```

My problem is that I need to press twice for the "generate certificates" button show the `div` with the contents.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What does `console.log(window.getComputedStyle(x).display)` reveal?

Comment: Hello xufox, as @Bijay Thapa commented. The condition does not let the element load on the dom.

Comment: Please use the "Post an Answer" box to post answers. Do not edit questions to include the answer in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the page for the first time, your gen_cert div is not loaded in dom, because of this condition: 
`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['gen_cert'])`

You can remove the onclick event and display:none on gen_cert div.

Or, if you want to show/hide the div using jquery, you don't need the form submit. You can change the input type submit to button, remove form 'my_form' and remove the condition 
`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['gen_cert'])`

Comment: But if I remove the condition, the certificates will be generated automatically, due to the `<?php require("cert_generate.php"); ?` option is set. How do I execute this option only when the `Generate Certificates' button is pressed?

Comment: In that case, maybe you just need to remove style="display:none" from div with id 'gen_cert' so it will be visible on postback.

Comment: Thanks @Bijay Thapa!!! Removing the style from within the div has solved the problem. I do not know how I did not do this before, but anyway, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Attach a double click event on the button

```
<p ondblclick="downloadCA(id)">Download da CA</p>
```

The `id` here is whatever you want to be in the fid query string in your url.

Then put this js code in your script

```
function downloadCA(id){
   window.location.href = 'download.php?fid=' + id;
}
```